# Create linear motion with Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

What I'm trying to do seems very simple, yet I'm struggling to make it work. I'm creating a simple SpriteKit game, similar to FlappyBird. The main character stays vertically stationary while the user controls its horizontal motion. That part is no problem. At the same time, other game elements should be moving vertically at a constant speed. I need to detect contact, but do not need to react with physics to the contact (the moving elements either disappear on contact, or the contact causes game to end).

I've tried using physicsBody.velocity, but the results are erratic. Conceptually, this is my desired approach because I want to control the velocity, speeding or slowing as the game progresses.

I've also tried using Actions, and this works ok but it's challenging to create constant motion, and it's difficult to imagine how to speed and slow the motion with Actions. My best results are with SKAction.sequence, but have difficulty coordinating multiple elements to move in sync.

Any clues would be most appreciated.

Comment: You are not clear in what it is your are asking. What results are erratic and what exactly are you having an issue with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the host node – `world: SKNode` to control all the moving objects – just add them as childs. And use that node to rule the world – set `world.speed = 0.0` to stop all `SKActions`, `world.speed = 2.0` to move them twice as faster